# using ASMX webservice in remote server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm going to use a web service for sending SMS, I made an small test app in my local system (VS2010, ASP.NET), it worked fine, but now I'm going to integrate this web service in my remote server, I'm confused about using this service on the remote server, I don't know exactly what and where I should copy to my server? also how should I change my web.config and/or other files in order to support this web service, this is how I use it in my local app:

```
com.panelesms.www.Send s = new com.panelesms.www.Send();
long[] rec = null;
byte[] status = null;
string[] to = new string[1];
to[0] = "mynumber";

int returnValue = s.SendSms("username", "pass", to, "sendernumber", "text", false, "", ref rec, ref status);
```

but com.panelesms.www.Send is not detected on remote server, I think I'm missing something, for example making changes in web.config, or copying some files to server so that com.panelesms.www.Send can be used as a valid type, this is my service address:
http://www.panelesms.com/Post/Send.asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the web service proxy address in your web.config file to point to the service http://www.panelesms.com/Post/Send.asmx.

If you are going to expose it externally, do invest time in protecting your services